# jQuery click event not firing on even clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, switch-statement, click

I have assigned a click event to an icon like so:

```
$('#nextMatches i').click(function(){
          dropdownClickCount += 1;
          var CC = dropdownClickCount; console.log(CC)
          var Len = matches.length;
          var liNum;

          function addPrev() {
                $('#prevMatches').addClass('prev-in-play');
            }
            function addNext() {
                $('#nextMatches').addClass('next-in-play');
            }
            function subPrev() {
                $('#prevMatches').removeClass('prev-in-play');
            }
            function subNext() {
                $('#nextMatches').removeClass('next-in-play');
            }
            function scrollFull() {
                $('ul#matchesDropdown').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('ul#matchesDropdown').prop("scrollHeight")
                    }, 'fast');
            }
            function scrollToLi() {
                console.log("liNum is: "+liNum);
                $('ul#matchesDropdown').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('ul#matchesDropdown li:nth-child('+liNum+')').position().top
                    }, 'fast');
            }

        if (Len >= 7 && Len <= 12) {
            switch (CC) {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    addPrev();
                    subNext();
                    scrollFull();
                    break;
                }
            }
        else if (Len >= 13 && Len <= 18) {
            switch (CC) {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    liNum = 7;
                    addPrev();
                    scrollToLi();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    subNext();
                    scrollFull();
                    break;
                }
            }
        else if (Len >= 19 && Len <= 24) {
            switch (CC) {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    liNum = 7;
                    addPrev();
                    scrollToLi();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    liNum = 13;
                    scrollToLi();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    subNext();
                    scrollFull();
                    break;
                }
            }
});
```

and encountered a small problem: in the `if-else` where `Len >= 19 && Len <= 24`, the `scrollToLi()` function does not actually execute the scroll animation when `case 2` is true. It logs the value of `liNum` as per the `console.log("liNum is: "+liNum);` call, but does not animate. However, when the icon is clicked again, it fires `case 3`. What is happening here and how can I ffix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your functions outside of the event and pass the variable as an argument to the `scrollToLi` function like :

```
function scrollToLi( liNum ) {
  console.log("liNum is: " + liNum);

  $('ul#matchesDropdown').animate({
    scrollTop: $('ul#matchesDropdown li:nth-child(' + liNum + ')').position().top
  }, 'fast');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that did not work. It still behaves as described.

Comment: You're welcome, could you create a live fiddle that reproduces your issue?